# Multicast with Docker Swarm and overlay network

Tags: networking, docker, docker-swarm

I am testing an application using multicast for the discovery. I created a Swarm cluster and a `network create -d overlay swarm-net` so the containers share the same LAN across the several Swarm agents hosts.

The discovery seemed to not be working, so I installed `tshark`.  `tshark` shows the IP address node within which `tshark` is running and the multicast address for the packet being *sent* though `tshark` **does not** show any incoming multicast packet.

Note that, as I don't know a better way to do so, the container is run with `--privileged` to enable `tshark`.
Note also that containers can communicate with each other.

Is the multicast blocked because of Docker iptable?
How to enable multicast in an overlay network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overlay-driver network **does not support multicast** as it uses vxlan unicast, according to [chanwit](https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/1691#issuecomment-175660544) (and my experience so far).

Note that the plugin [weave net](http://www.weave.works/products/weave-net/) (an overlay network driver) **does** support multicast!

Comment: Any tutorial on how to set up a multicast network using weave?

Comment: i'm trying hazelcast embedded in a java application, and scaling the service does not discover nodes. I've set weave to enable multicast but it's not working. Any example?