# Hazelcast node not discovering other node when use docker stack deploy

Tags: java, spring, docker, hazelcast

I need to setup a hazelcast for web application with multiple replication factors in docker environment and using docker swarm to deploy the app in multi host using overlay network.

I am facing the problem that service are not able to discover the other node in swarm mode, however working fine in docker compose. I am using below config for hazelcast configuration.

```
<port auto-increment="true">5701</port>
<join>
  <multicast enabled="false">
    <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
    <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
  </multicast>
  <tcp-ip enabled="true">
    <member>hazelcast-master</member>
  </tcp-ip>

</join>
```

here hazelcast-master is my service name in docker.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In application start up logs : Cannot resolve hostname 'hazelcast-master'. Please make sure host is valid and reachable

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure your docker network? Is hazelcast-master in your DNS server? By default docker uses the same DNS as the host, but if you for example put hazelcast-master in /etc/hosts, your docker guest will not see it and won't be able to use it. Either use IP address of the host, put full host domain name (from DNS) or use --add-host when running docker container.

Comment: I used the default network which is created when docker-compose is ran. hazelcast-master is just a normal docker container.

I am using the docker-compose for deploying the app, so is there any tag in docker-compose where i can add the entry for host

Comment: Paste your docker-compose.yml.

Also, run the following command docker exec -ti <name of the container that can't see hazelcast-master>  ping hazelcast-master
and see if the name is resolved.

Comment: I used following config in my docker-compose:

version: '3.7'

services:

  hazelcast-master:
    build:
      context: context/trade-hazelcast
    image: hazelcast
    ports:
      - "5701:5701"
  hazelcast-workers:
    build:
      context: context/trade-hazelcast
    image: hazelcast
    depends_on:
      - hazelcast-master
#    deploy:
#      mode: replicated
#      replicas: 1
    ports:
        - "5702:5701"

Answer (score 0):

I think that mutlicast may not work (at least out of the box) in Docker Swarm. Read [this](https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/1691) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039612/multicast-with-docker-swarm-and-overlay-network). Docker Compose works only because it's deployed on one single host machine.

What you can do is try to use the [Hazelcast Docker Swarm Discovery Plugin](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker%20swarm%20hazelcast&oq=docker%20swarm%20hazelcast&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6403j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Other than that, the other option is the static TCP-IP configuration, which probably does not make much sense in Docker Swarm.

Comment: I tried to setup this using discovery but getting exception:
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 10.101.129.51:2375 [/10.101.129.51] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

I tried to increase the timeout but no luck in docker container, however when i ran the test code outside container then it works.

Comment: He doesn't use multicast for the purpose of discovery. He is using enumerated memebers with tcp ip config and if the docker-compose.yml is correct, he should be able to connect to the other hosts.

Comment: I am able to connect using  Hazelcast Docker Swarm Discovery Plugin but for that I have to do the following steps:
1. changed the docker daemon socker default to tcp
2. Opened the docker swarm port and allowed the traffic from docker and worker using ucf.

I assume, if I enabled the socket to tcp then discovery should happen automatically if I specify service name in member list. I tried this but not worked. I think I missed something here.