# setup activemq cluster in docker swarm

Tags: docker, activemq-classic, swarm

subject line:  setup activemq cluster in docker swarm .

Problem Summary: - Unable to create a setup with two active-active activemq nodes  in docker swarm. so need your help to setup that. following are the details of setup I am trying to create.

Details:
Trying to create two node activemq cluster (not AMQ Artemis) in docker swarm setup.
docker version is 19.03.12
following vms used to setup my application.

1. node-infra - This vm is swarm leader and has "activemq" container
2. node-infra2 -This vm is another swarm leader and has "activemq" container.
3. node-app  - This vm is worker node which has my application running.

root@node-infra:~# docker node ls

ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION

ypzb7jmys3qzyea5r4r1te5b6     node-app            Ready               Active                                  19.03.12

byuar7z0uphd01zlujy9iy0n1 *   node-infra          Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.12

tvjzzlamc29gzrsnq3xn3e58w     node-infra2         Ready               Active              Reachable           19.03.12

created following overlay docker network in this setup.
docker network create --driver=overlay --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 --attachable mynetwork

Used following command to start activemq containers in both node-infra nodes.
docker run -d --restart unless-stopped --net mynetwork --log-opt mode=non-blocking --log-opt max-buffer-size=4m  -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161 --name activemq rmohr/activemq:5.15.3-alpine

rest of the entries are default but following entries are changed.

activemq.xml entries are as below for node-infra node

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="master_infra" brokerId="master_id_infra" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulerSupport="true">
<networkConnectors>
<networkConnector name="default-nc" prefetchSize="10" uri="multicast://default" />
</networkConnectors>
<transportConnectors>
 <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"  rebalanceClusterClients="true" updateClusterClients="true" discoveryUri="multicast://default"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

similarly for node-infra2  following are the activemq.xml entries.

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="master_infra2" brokerId="master_id_infra2" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulerSupport="true">
<networkConnectors>
<networkConnector name="default-nc" prefetchSize="10" uri="multicast://default" />
</networkConnectors>
<transportConnectors>
 <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"  rebalanceClusterClients="true" updateClusterClients="true" discoveryUri="multicast://default"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

when I start container activemq on node-infra and activemq on node-infra2 .
eventhough I have enabled multicast discovery, both containers are not able to establish connection with eachother. there is no error in log , but it doesnt sense that there is another activemq container with multicast discovery enabled.

when I did this setup directly on vm without containers, it works as expected both activemq instances share messaged over multicast network. but not happening with docker containers.

Can someone please help on this. let me know if more info required to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Docker overlay network does not support multicast. It looks like your broker relies on multicast to find other active nodes.

See also [Multicast with Docker Swarm and overlay network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039612/multicast-with-docker-swarm-and-overlay-network)

Comment: thanks. so until we get the support from docker, I am not using multicast now.

Comment: There are network plugins (?) for Docker that support multicast. I have not used them.